# Automatic Ejabberd clustering with EC2 (Amazon Web Services)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, xmpp, ejabberd

Using [Ejabberd](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/) in [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) as an [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) server to send real-time information to clients...

How it is possible to set up clustering so that if the load on the server gets too much, [Auto Scaling](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) will create a new EC2 instance that is part of the Ejabberd cluster?

The [documentation I've read](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#htoc86) suggests that you must already have the machines and manually configure each new one to be added to the cluster. Surely though you don't have to be running redundant EC2 instances just in case?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do this manually, however a single ejabberd server can handle quite a lot of traffic.  Each server adds a significant amount of available connections to your cluster, so it's not a common task.

That said, I'd really be careful running ejabberd in EC2.  I've been doing it for about a year, and we fight mnesia network partitioning pretty regularly.  Clustered ejabberd servers don't work very reliably in the EC2 network.

Comment: Which is the EC2 instance size you recommend for running clustered ejabberd on EC2? I mean, is it better to use small instances with more nodes, or large instances with fewer nodes? Thanks

Comment: Generally, erlang scales quite well to put a lot of users on a smaller number of nodes.  You obviously need to plan for high availability if you do this though.  That's a topic for a different question though.

Comment: 1. In what environment would you suggest to run ejabberd other than EC2 to handle millions of active connections? 2. How bad where the ejabberd+EC2 issues? (efficiency problems on some of the nodes, or all out down time?...)

Answer (score 1):

I am installing an infrastructure based on EC2 + ejabberd and have read this post. Do not you recommend? I planned to use as backend mysqlk (in AWS RDS) for tables that store large amounts of data. What do you think?