# Chat App on AWS: EC2 (eJabberd XMPP) vs RDS (Relational Database) vs other options?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd, amazon-rds

I want to create an iOS app for 1:1 and group chats. Since [DynamoDB is not the ideal solution for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213738/storing-chat-log-on-aws-dynamodb), I am currently searching for a better way.

Possible solutions:

1. Install an XMPP server (eJabbered) on AWS EC2
2. Use AWS RDS (relational database) with one chat table, where each record equals a message sent from one client to another or to a group.
3. Use Amazon S3 to store files for each chat?
4. Other options?

Which one of the above is most elegant / easiest solution for this?
Option 1 is not recommended by [some.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593584/automatic-ejabberd-clustering-with-ec2-amazon-web-services?rq=1) Option 2 seems to be easier to (auto) scale.

Which one is more cost-efficient?
Regarding RDS Amazon writes:

**"AWS Free Tier includes 750hrs of Micro DB Instance each month for one year"**

Regarding EC2 Amazon writes:

**"AWS Free Tier includes 750 hours of Linux and Windows t2.micro instances each month for one year. To stay within the Free Tier, use only EC2 Micro instances."**

I am quite new to server backend architecture, but an accounting based on time seems not to be the best solution for a chat app?

Comment: There's no right answer to this; just opinions (and tool recommendations). Off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, I was hoping for an answer like "Option X is really bad, because...". Right now I am prone to use a AWS RDS and SQL for storing the chat.

Comment: Hi can you please help me on how did you achieve real time chat messaging with RDS?

Answer (score 2):

**The S3** solution is not the one to choose because the limit of PUT Authorized on Amazon S3 is too small (2000), so if you are going to have millions of chat conversation, your cost will be amazing.

Currently i'm using **AWS RDS** for a chat feature on my android/ios application.
This solution works fine because my database and your server application are scalable, but i'm not sure it's the better solution to use.

*Conclusion*
**If i have to start a new chat application today, i will choose XMPP server for low cost and better performance.**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. See my edited answer. It seems like (auto) scaling eJabberd / XMPP on AWS EC2 is not an easy job to handle.

Comment: autoscaling any connected protocol is not a good idea, because it users will need to be kicked out if you want to scale down, as opposed to HTTP that is requests and response and is easy to autoscale.

Comment: What would you say is the best way to scale a eJabberd server?

Comment: Hii, I am also wanting to use RDS but have no idea on how to use real-time chat feature in RDS. Can you please guide me on this?